# How can I delete using pyral

Tags: python, pyral

I want to delete UserIterationCapacity from Rally. The Syntax provided is `delete(entityName, itemIdent, workspace=None, project=None)`. How to I provide the Item Identifer or itemIdent?

I know the details of the record I need to delete is below.

```
oid       : 332661613164
ref       : useriterationcapacity/332661613164
ObjectID  : 332661613164
```

I have tried to use the below syntax.

```
info = { "ObjectID" : 332661613164,
    "Workspace" : Workspace,
    "Project" : Project
}

UserIterationCapacity_ID = rally_all_rights.delete('UserIterationCapacity', info )
```

I get below error.

```
 RallyResponseError: Response for request: useriterationcapacity/{'ObjectID': 332661613164, 'Workspace': 'workspace/182531535356', 'Project': 'project/199932093140'}?key=None&workspace=workspace/182531535356&project=project/199932093140&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=false either was not JSON content or was an invalidly formed/incomplete JSON structure
```